# Difference between MISSING and NULL in SAS

Tags: sas

In SAS, while using in a WHERE clause, is there any differnece between

```
WHERE col1 is MISSING
```

vs

```
WHERE col1 is NULL
```

Can you explain citing the case when col1 is char and when col1 is numeric?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WHERE col1 is NULL` and `WHERE col1 is MISSING` are identical: SAS translates between the two freely (the documentation refers to them as one).  Both pick up character missing, numeric missing, and numeric special missings (`.M` etc.) fine.

See [the SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473690.htm) for more specific information on `IS NULL` / `IS MISSING`.

---

Note that this is only true for SAS-side processing.  If you're connected to another kind of database/data source (such as Oracle, SQL Server, etc.), these do not necessarily apply - even if you're running it in PROC SQL with a LIBNAME.

Comment: Perhaps add some distinction for how non-SAS libnames and ODBC passthrough may behave differently?

Comment: Yeah, I meant to put that in and then forgot-thanks!